# Update UILabel automatically

Tags: swift

I'm trying to update an `UILabel` based on the numbers inserted in an `UITextField`.

`UITextField`, lets say 45 was inserted

A function that does (45 * 2)

`UILabel` will now becomes 90

I am having trouble exporting values from the function and updating the `UILabel`.

Comment: What type of problem you are facing? Can you please explain more?

Answer (score 0):

Please add a target to the textfield text change in `viewDidLoad` like below

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textChanges(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
```

And get the changes in here

```
func textChanges(_ textField: UITextField) {

    let text = textField.text! 

    let value = Int(text) * 2

    self.lbl.text = "\(value)"
}
```

Hope it helps.